# How to use two different yaxis?

Tags: gnuplot

I tried:

```
set ytics nomirror 
set xtics nomirror 
set x1range [-0.4:1.8]
set y1range [25:0]
set y2range [17:-8]
plot 'file.txt' axis x1y1 using 2:1 with point, 'file2.txt' axis x1y2 using 2:1 with point
```

I would like to plot two files with different range in y-axis in a way that the value of the point from file will be 0 and the value of point from file2 will be -8 and these two points will be in the constant line. Without seeing the ticks of y-axes it will seem they have same value. Thank you

Comment: As shown, your two y axes run in opposite directions. (y1min > y1max, y2min < y2max). Is that what you intended?

Comment: I am sorry, I editted it.

Answer (score 1):

```
set link y2 via y-8 inverse y+8
set ytics nomirror
set y2tics nomirror
```

However this seems overly complex for what you describe.  It would be simpler to use only one y axis but filter the input. In this case there are no separate y2 tic labels because the y2 axis is not used.

```
plot 'file.txt' using 2:1 with point, 'file2.txt' using 2:($1 + 8.) with point
```

Comment: Thank you and how to print yticks of the second scale to the right y-axis?